# Ajax feed parse well in Chrome, but No in Firefox and Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox, xml-parsing

**I have this Code:**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "news.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            parseXml(xml);
        }
    });
});

function parseXml(xml) {
    $(xml).find("entry").each(function() {

        var newlistId = $(this).find('newlistId').text();
        var nombresillo = $(this).find('title').text();

        $(".list").append("<li class='name'> <a onclick=\"LCO.loadNews('https://website.com/results?item=" + newlistId + "');\" href='#'>" + nombresillo + "</a></li>");
    });
};
</script>
```

**Works only in CHROME, but no in FIREFOX AND IE.**

**Results when .append...:
in CHROME:**

`<a onclick="LCO.loadNews('https://website.com/results?item=xxxx');" href="#">Today News</a>` (well done!)

**in FIREFOX and IE** (Missing [xxxx])

```
<a onclick="LCO.loadNews('https://website.com/results?item=');" href="#">Today News</a>
```

What can be happening?

**THE XML:**

```
<entry>
    <title>News 1</title>
    <link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='http://www.website.com/news/item-d5d6s1' />
    <yt:newlistId>d5d6s1</yt:newlistId>
</entry>
```

Comment: Don't use inline events! So is `console.log(newlistId, nombresillo);` returning nothing? Does `console.log($(this).find('newlistId'))` find anything? Debug it

Comment: the XML is: 

<pre><entry>
    <title>News 1</title>
    <link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='http://www.website.com/news/item-15' />
    <yt:newlistId>d5d6s1</yt:newlistId>
</entry></pre>

Comment: Well technically that is not valid XML. Or does it have `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
 and you did not show it?